# How to replace @ResourceAdapter which is imported from "org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter" while migrating from Jboss 6.3.3 to Liberty server?

Tags: websphere-liberty, jboss6.x

I am migrating existing application from JBOSS 6.3.3 to Liberty server. I have found that MDB class is using @ResourceAdapter("wmq.jmsra.rar") which is imported from "org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter". How can I replace it with Liberty provided Jars?

@ResourceAdapter("wmq.jmsra.rar")

public class QueueListenerBean implements MessageListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the Jboss-specific `@ResourceAdapter("wmq.jmsra.rar")` annotation with `@MessageDriven`,

```
@MessageDriven("MyMDB")
public class QueueListenerBean implements MessageListener
```

after which you can configure an `activationSpec` for it in server.xml,

```
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
    <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
    ... other features
  </featureManager>

  <resourceAdapter id="wmqjmsra" location="C:/adapters/wmq/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>

  <jmsActivationSpec id="MyMDB">
    <properties.wmqjmsra .../>
  </jmsActivationSpec>
```

The above should work in both OpenLiberty as well as the commercial WebSphere Liberty.  If using the latter, you have another alternative for server.xml configuration,

```
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
    <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
    <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>
    ... other features
  </featureManager>

  <variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="C:/adapters/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>

  <jmsActivationSpec id="MyMDB">
    <properties.wmqJms .../>
  </jmsActivationSpec>
```

The following [knowledge center doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.zos.doc/ae/rwlp_config_jmsActivationSpec.html) shows available config attributes on jmsActivationSpec and properties.wmqJms